# Android : Cannot install earlier packages

Tags: android, sdk

I have successfully installed Level 13 (3.2) during the Android SDK installation, but chose not to include any earlier levels at that time.

I now would like to install 2.2 or 2.3, but in the SDK / AVD manager I get the message:-

> Failed to fetch URL
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list.xml, reason:
>   File not found

I've looked this up in other posts and so run the SDK manager with Administrator permissions, and have turned off the firewall. Eventually, it comes back with SDK tools revision 15, and SDK PLatform tools revision 9 only.

1. Should I have installed earlier packages during setup?
2. Would an uninstall / reinstall cure this behaviour? (Reluctant to do
   this :-( for obvious reasons)
3. Is it possible to get earlier levels having installed just level 13?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old Android SDK tool (r13 and earlier) fetch/download available SDK from here [repository](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml), after google release r14 and r15, they remove all SDK verion and only leave r15 in this URL, that means they want you use the latest SDK tool r15.

New Andorid SDK tool (r14 and r15) fetch/download available SDK from a new URL [repository-5](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml), which contains everything downloadable.

If you are not using anything else like Maven (currently incompatible with latest ADT) with your project, the simplest answer is upgrade both your Android SDK tools and ADT Eclipse plugin.

Comment: OK, latest version it is then. Thanks for the info, and to Daniel also. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I just setted up my android environment yesterday - try to download the package manually and load them as Archive files, this worked for me! ;)

Comment: Hi, Where can I download them manually? I looked in the 2.2 & 2.3 platform SDK pages, but there are no links to download. I looked here :- http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.2.html